# Getting parameter from dropdown and passing to controller with value from model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have tried searching this out but can't seem to land on a fix for this probably simple problem I'm having with when creating a web app. Currently, I'm using an Actionlink but it is not a requirement. A button would also be fine. I'm trying to pass two parameters from a row in a table which removes a name from a group in Active Directory:

```
        @foreach (var r in Model)
        {
        ...etc
         <td>
           Html.ActionLink("Remove", "Remove", new { r.Sam, \\group name from ddl })
         </td>
```

In the Actionlink is the SamAccountName (r.Sam) which works but GroupName needs to come from a dropdown called "dllGroups" and both parameters are passed to:

public ActionResult Remove(string id, string GroupName)

It works if I hard code GroupName but passes null each time when trying getting both parameters filled via code. If I go to function using Ajax which I believe should be the correct method (using onclick grpName in the Actionlink), I'm stuck with not knowing how to get the SamAccountName from the model.

An example of the function I'm trying:

```
    function grpName(id) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home/Remove",
            data: {
                id: id,
                GroupName: $('#dllGroups').val(),
            },
            datatype: "HTML",
            success: function (data) { },
            error: function (data, status, error) { }
        });
    }
```

Thanks for any assistance. As you probably have guessed I'm pretty new still but working hard on learning it.

Comment: `$('#dllGroups').val` should be `$('#dllGroups').val()` - val is a [jQuery function](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: Sorry about missing that in the copy and paste.You are correct, but unfortunately I had already added the parens there earlier and it still didn't go.

Comment: I managed to get this working using a button and using data-id. Here is the button:  <input id="btnRemove" type="button" value="Remove" data-id="@r.Sam" onclick="getGroup()" />